# How to align a picture with the text besides it

Tags: html, css

Hello I want to make a website with multiple div-boxes. And the pictures I want to use should be next to the text in a box where the are forced to fit (not scaled). Please focus on the divs #conten-articles. In there are four articles which should later be able to be configured by an external tool. Their float is alternating between left and right, and the picture should always be at the opposite site of the #content-articles div. Hope I described my problem so you understand.

Thanks for your help ;)

```css
@charset "utf-8";

html{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background: #F2F2F2; 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: expresswayregular;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'expresswayregular';
    src: url('fonts/expressway_rg-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/expressway_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#header {
 position: fixed;
 background: #333333;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 top: 0;
}

#header-content {
 background: #333333;
 width: 1280px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#logo {
 position: absolute;
}

#currentsite-info font {
 position: absolute;
 height: 30px;
 width: auto;
 margin-left: 60px;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 26px;
}

#search-box {
 width: 400px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

#search {
 background: #fff;
 width: 356px;
 height: 16px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 6px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px; 
}

#submit {
 float: right;
 background: #fff;
 width: 29px;
 height: 28px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0; 
}

#menu {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-linkbox a{
 position: static;
 float: right;
 width: 60px;
 height: 14px;
 top: 0;
 padding: 18px 15px 18px 15px;
 color: #F2F2F2;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu-linkbox:hover a {
 color: #2997D3;
 transition: all 500ms;
}

#menu-linkbox-scene a {
 color: #2997D3;
}

#main-content {
 background: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 50px;
 overflow: auto;
}

#content-articles {
 background: #F2F2F2;
 width: 1220px;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 overflow: auto;
}

#article1 {
 width: 60%;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 30% 20px 60px;
 text-align: justify;
 word-spacing: 4px;
 border-right: 1px solid #2997D3;  
 border-left: 1px solid #2997D3; 
}

#article2 {
 width: 60%;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid #2997D3;
    border-left: 1px solid #2997D3;
}

#article2-photo2-box {
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px;
}

#photo2 {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}

#article3 {
 width: 60%;
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 30% 60px 80px;
 text-align: justify;
 word-spacing: 4px;
 border-right: 1px solid #2997D3;  
 border-left: 1px solid #2997D3; 
}

#article4 {
 width: 60%;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    border-right: 1px solid #2997D3;
    border-left: 1px solid #2997D3;
}

#player {
 background: #333333;
 position : fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
}

#player-content {
 background: #333333;
 width: auto;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-right: 200px;
 font-size: 25px;
 
}

h1 {
 color: #2997D3;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 20px; 
}

p {
 margin: 20px; 
}

a {
 color: #2997D3;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <head> 
 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_news.css">
  
  <link rel="icon" href="images/logo_site.png">
  
  <title>News</title>
 
  <script>
   function toggleNavPanel(x){
    var panel = document.getElementById(x), navarrow = document.getElementById("navarrow"), maxH="300px";
    if(panel.style.height == maxH){
     panel.style.height = "0px";
     navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9662;";
    } 
   
    else {
     panel.style.height = maxH;
     navarrow.innerHTML = "&#9652;";
    }
   }
  </script>
 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <div id="header">
  
   <div id="header-content">
  
    <img id ="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
    
    <div id="currentsite-info">
    
     <font>News</font>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="menu">     
     
     <div class="menu-linkbox" id="menu-linkbox-breaking"><a href="../Breaking/index_breaking.html">Breaking</a></div>
      
     <div class="menu-linkbox" id="menu-linkbox-live"><a href="../Live/index_live.html">Live</a></div> 

     <div class="menu-linkbox" id="menu-linkbox-scene"><a href="index_news.htnl">News</a></div>

     <div class="menu-linkbox" id="menu-linkbox-home"><a href="../../index.html">Home</a></div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div id="search-box">
   
     <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
   
      <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search">
   
      <input id="submit" type="image" src="images/search.png" alt="Submit">
   
     </form>
   
    </div>
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
  <div id="main-content">
  
   <div id="content-articles">
   
    <div id="article1"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
   
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
     
     <a href="https://www.google.de/">Weiterlesen</a>
     
     </p>
   
    </div>
    
    <div id="article2"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
   
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     <a href="https://www.google.de/">Weiterlesen</a>
   
     </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="article2-photo2-box">
    
     <img id ="photo2" src="images/footage/article1.jpeg" />
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="article3"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
     
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     <a href="https://www.google.de/">Weiterlesen</a>
   
     </p>
   
    </div>
    
    <div id="article4"> 
     
     <h1>Assignment</h1>
   
     <p>
   
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei ius audire utroque, eum et ferri delectus. Nonumy possim antiopam ius no, te sit posse quando, volumus legendos vel ea. Commodo fabellas sea id. No feugait ocurreret mediocritatem est, eu alia enim percipit his. Regione delicatissimi ea his, denique disputando has id, ne qui etiam placerat.

     Ne eligendi invidunt incorrupte sed, dolore luptatum periculis no mel. Has id theophrastus signiferumque, mea cu eirmod latine prodesset. Alia brute eligendi te sea, vis cu cibo nihil. Te dictas invenire rationibus vix.

     Ei has oratio appetere, possit fuisset pro id. Mei ea ullum primis. Cum ubique quaerendum an, an per dicit ocurreret definitionem. His ne ferri detraxit efficiendi. Cu prima iusto lucilius usu, mea no natum exerci, quis ullamcorper vel at.

     Eius pertinacia moderatius in eam. Usu iudico delenit ea. Assueverit mediocritatem te eum, et possim deterruisset eum. Sit id graeci epicurei suavitate, vidit ponderum suscipiantur has in, nam agam liberavisse reprehendunt ad.

     Per fuisset praesent ut, vim in rebum prompta mandamus. Abhorreant mnesarchum dissentiunt id his, mei id elitr soluta. Ex persius minimum deterruisset sit. Ex mea case idque elaboraret, natum abhorreant in est. Eu virtute diceret salutatus ius, ne qui purto porro prompta.
   
     <a href="https://www.google.de/">Weiterlesen</a>
   
     </p>
   
    </div>
    
   
   </div>
  
  </div>
  
 <!--
  <div id="player">
   
   <div id="player-content">
   
   
   
   </div> 

  </div>
 -->
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the exact way, your code is working now and how you want it to? because, the snippet working as your description.

Comment: @miestiec this is precisely the kind of thing that Flexbox was invented for. I'm not sure I'm understanding your question properly, but here is a link to an article that might help you; https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/